# How to make a post open a specific link

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress blog, I want to make a specific post open a specific link, that is when someone clicks on this post, I don't want the post to open, instead I want to redirect the visitor to a new link that I already know.

Can you please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Then at which point are you unable to solve this problem on your own? What part do you not know how to do? You have posted a work description, not a specific question.

Comment: @ Dan Grossman My problem is that I can't find out where to edit so I can enter the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words you want to use one posts teaserview as a teaser for another post... I would recommend not doing it that way even though it is possible. I would rather write a different text in the Excerpt.

"The WordPress Excerpt is an optional summary or description of a post; in short, a post summary.

"The Excerpt has two main uses:

1. It replaces the full content in RSS
   feeds when the option to display
   summaries is selected in Dashboard ›
   Settings › Reading.

   Depending on the WordPress theme, it
   can be displayed in places where
   quick summaries are preferable to
   full content: Search results Tag
   archives Category archives Monthly
   archives Author archives
   "

To also show a different image when in teasermode I would use Custom Fields:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/29/extend-wordpress-with-custom-fields/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/